# R: Problems with unloadNamespace(package) when installing a package

Tags: r, installation, namespaces, package

I made an R-package called TRIMmaps and tried to install it with the command

```
R CMD INSTALL TRIMmaps_v1.12.0
```

I received the following error message:

```
Error in unloadNamespace(package) : 
  namespace ‘Rcpp’ is imported by ‘plyr’ so cannot be unloaded
Error in library(pkg, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE, lib.loc = lib.loc) : 
  “Rcpp” version 0.11.2 cannot be unloaded.
```

I do need package plyr, however, because when I remove it I get the message:

```
Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
  there is no package called ‘plyr’
```

I removed both packages `plyr` and `Rcpp` and installed them again. My current version of `Rcpp` now is 0.11.5, but when I try to install the TRIMmaps-package again, I get the same error message as above including the line `“Rcpp” version 0.11.2 cannot be unloaded`. Although I have removed the older Rcpp-version and replaces it by 0.11.5, here still a problem occurs with 0.11.2.

How do I solve this? Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to install on a clean instance, i.e. without packages already attached?

Comment: @alexforrence: I invoked R CMD INSTALL from the Linux command line, so I assume no packages were attached. Other instances of R, however, were open. Can this cause problems?

Answer (score 6):

I get a similar error.  Minimal conditions to reproduce it seem to be:

1. `Depend` on a package `x` (in my case `reshape`)
2. In your vignette load a packge `y` (in my case `plyr`) that also imports or depends on `x`.

The vignette builds fine if you build it outside of the package building or checking process, but throws the error that you indicate otherwise.  The error is also R version and maybe site specific, since it goes away with R 3.2.0 when trying to build the package on a different machine.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to close (R-Studio), or open a new (GUI), and do the job, and you can copy your code and reuse them.

Answer (score 0):

**#This package is not installed ,but use tamp :

```
install.packages("tamp", dependencies=TRUE)
```

If you mean TRIM MAP SITE:
https://www2.gov.bc.ca/gov/content/data/geographic-data-services/topographic-data/raster-base-maps

#derderi**

Answer (score -1):

In search box, type `command prompt`

In the command prompt, *change directory* to the place that contains the R package.

Build R package using `R CMD build pkgName`. For example I use `R CMD build cum*. A tar.gz`

The file is built under the working directory.

[There's a PDF Tutorial](https://www.stt.msu.edu/%7Ecui/Groupmeeting/R_package_tutorial.pdf) that goes more in-depth.